# Why output redirection is not working with the mplayer command?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, scripts

The mplayer command is used to play a media file in terminal or a shell script and i gives some controls over it like move forward, backward in the file, etc.
Sometimes i find it annoying so i want it to work silently without any output so i put this: `> /dev/null` at the end of command to make it not printing anything on the screen, the file played but not silently as i expected.
[image]

so what this mean ?
Also i want the prompt not to wait until the file ends to give me the next prompt(i.e, i want to play the command in the background), How ?

Comment: That is some cool shell output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mplayer [] > /dev/null` only redirects `mplayer`'s `stdout` to `/dev/null`; to completely disable any output you need to redirect its `stderr` to `/dev/null` as well.

Use `mplayer [] &> /dev/null` instead

Comment: that works thanks but what about making the command play in the background ?

Comment: @Naruto I didn't even notice the second question, I have no idea. Maybe you should ask another question since those are actually two questions!